# Cannot setBool NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to set userDefaults, but it isn't working. Have anyone else experience this problem? 
Tried both on simulator and device. Xcode 6.3.1 and iOS 8.3

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"active"];
BOOL active = [defaults boolForKey:@"active"]; // RETURN NO
```

Comment: [defaults synchronize]; have you use this line of code

Comment: You will need to synchronise the `NSUserDefaults` as well after setting the value.

Comment: @BlackMouse i think you code is right. i have checked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chek this code: 
you missing synchronize nsuserdefault.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"active"];
[defaults synchronize];
BOOL active = [defaults boolForKey:@"active"];
```